# The Second image is not visible

Tags: html, css

Hey I have a little problem and i can't solve it.

Here is the CSS:

```
.error {
  float: left;
  color: #F00;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: inline;  
}
.validieren:required:invalid + .error {
   visibility: visible;
}

.right {
  float: left;
  color: #0F0;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: inline;
}

.validieren:required:valid + .right {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

And here is the HTML Code:

```
<img src="haken.gif" class="right"> <img src="kreuz.gif" class="error">
```

The problem is that the second (in this case error) image doesn't appear.

Thanks for your help.

Sorry for my language i'm german.

Comment: This is the weirdest question i've seen so far...you explicitly tell the image to be hidden by applying the error class to it.

Comment: the rest of the code doesn't matter. If you don't understand the Code why do you comment it ? yeah i tell the image to be hidden but if the element with the class _validieren_ is invalid it should appear

Comment: well apparently it did matter where in relation to your image .validieren was...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.validieren:required:invalid ~ .error {
   visibility: visible;
}
```

You have both `.validieren + .error` and `.validieren + .right`.

`.validieren` can't be immediately followed ([adjacent sibling selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector)) by *both* `.error` and `.right`.

Changing to the [general sibling selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector) should make it work. I'm assuming that the `.validieren` element comes before (and shares the same parent as) both the images.

Answer (score 0):

You have `visibility: hidden` set for the `error` class, which is assigned to the second image. What behavior are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your `error` class contains an attribute (specifically `visibility: hidden`) that forces your image (or element) to not display.